# Why does this MySQL statement not work when inside a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is it that this statement works on its own, but when it is part of a subquery, it says invalid use of group function

```
select count(cid) 
  from qualification q 
       inner join faculty f 
           on q.fid=f.fid 
           where fname='Berry'
group by 
       f.fid;
```

How would I modify it to suit a subquery?

Whole query -

```
select fid, fname from faculty
where fid in
(select fid from qualification where count(cid)=
    (select count(cid) from qualification q inner join faculty f on
    q.fid=f.fid where fname='Berry' group by f.fid));
```

Logic : list fname and fid of all faculty members who can teach all the courses that Prof. Berry can teach

Comment: Can you please show the whole query?

Comment: Aggregate functions filter must be used with `HAVING` not `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem is using `count()` inside `WHERE`

```
where count(cid)=
(select count(cid) from qualification q inner join faculty f on
q.fid=f.fid where fname='Berry' group by f.fid)
```

You can try to change it to to process like this

```
HAVING count(cid)=
(select count(cid) from qualification q inner join faculty f on
q.fid=f.fid where fname='Berry' group by f.fid)
```

but I don't understand the logic. If you explain more we would suggest a better solution